# How to export SSRS 2008 R2 report(.rdl) to excel with formulas

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export-to-excel, formulas, officewriter

I want to export SSRS 2008 R2 report (.rdl) to excel with formulas. Is OfficeWriter API has this feature? If yes, can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in adv.
Mohan.

Comment: Or is this possible through any other API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is possible with OfficeWriter. I would take a look at their documents located at

- http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/RS10/Creating+Your+First+Report
- http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/RS10/How+to+Create+Excel+Reports

Comment: Yes, thank you Sam. i started working on that already hope i can achieve this ...

Comment: Hi Sam, i tried to add a custom extension and its showing in report manager service in the export options as "Excel designed by OfficeWriter" but when i selected that option i am getting the error as "Error SA008050: This report was not designed for the selected OfficeWriter rendering extension"

Comment: Mohan,

You would have to create your report with the OfficeWriter designer as the expection indicates. The OfficeWriter designer report does not convert reports it is its own reporting platform.

Comment: It worked like a magic Sam, thank you very much. Also, i want to change the extension display name but after include the below code in RsReportServer.config file and when i tried to restart the Reporting service its giving an error like "the reporting service is started and stopped ...", what i missed here?                                    
        <OverrideNames>  
            <Name Language="en-US">My Extension</Name>  
        </OverrideNames>

Comment: Oops sorry the XML tag was not closed properly so i couldn't change the extension display name, now its working good. Thanks once again Sam :)